# Your request cannot be processed - cross-origin script error

Tags: jhipster

I'm attempting to build the most basic application using JHipster.

I've followed the instructions from the website and started the web application using ./mvnw.  Everything looks fine.

**But** when I attempt open it in Chrome it fails to display the application's page but instead says:

```
your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: Not Found
```

When I use the developer tools in Chrome I can see the following error:

```
A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&hl=en&site=localhost%3A8080&error=http404&js=true, is invoked via document.write. 

This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

hb @ fixurl.js:135
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Kind regards,
Fergal.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was.

The java application had not been fully generated.

The reason for this was that the version of **yarn** that had been installed was an older version than the expected/required **version**. Once I updated yarn, and generated a completely new app, the app ran as expected/per the website.

(Note: perhaps a check should be built into the system to abort if the min required version of dependencies have not been installed.  That'd be very helpful.)

Comment: How did you figured this out? 
I'm getting the same error once ./mvnw is called. But I didn't noted any yarn issue when generating the UAA application...

Comment: And you have checked to see if the version of yarn that you are using is correct ? and you checked to see if there is a global instance ?